# numpy.save saved a file with zero dimension

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I was working with a human pose estimation model which can generate pose heatmaps with the shape `[p k h w]` where p is the number of person in the frame, k is the number of keypoints (like head, hand etc.) and rest is height and width. I save this numpy to the disk using `numpy.save` and everything seems fine. I run this model of around 15K videos (around 1 million frames in total) and I find that in some cases (just 10-15 frames out of a million) the file saved has a shape like `[0 17 96 72]`.

My question is,

1. How did it possibly created and saved the array with a dimension size = 0. In my opinion, if there's no person in the frame, the heatmap array should simply be none and not an array with a dimension = 0.
2. Now that the model has already been run on 15K videos and it's time consuming to rerun, is there a way to convert array of shape `[0 17 96 72]` to `[1 17 96 72]`? I tried numpy.squeeze() or converting to the list but nothing works.

Comment: `None` is a unique python object.  It is not a numpy array.  And yes, an array can have a shape like that.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, an array `a` of shape (0, 17, 96, 72) is equivalent to an 'empty' array `[]` or `np.empty(0)`. So, 'converting' such an empty array to an array of shape (1, 17, 96, 72) should be equivalent to creating a new array of the desired shape (filled with any desired value):

```
a = np.full((1,) + a.shape[1:], None)
```

Does that help?